# Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

Tags: c#, .net

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Error:

> Before the establishment of the first object IWin32Window in the annex to call SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault.

Why error? How to avoid? What does `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` actually do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: as stated in the comments, the answer was wrong. I changed it below and referenced the MSDN article instead of rephrasing it.

As the docs state, you have to call this before creating your first window.

It sets the default rendering engine for some controls: GDI+ if true, GDI if false.
See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault.aspx) for all the details.

Comment: but can I ever use it in console application ? because I had a try set it right after main() {

Comment: If you are writing a console application, you do not need to call this function, it would have no effect if it succeeded.

Comment: @Timores even if you are using a console application you can create Labels, you cannot display these Labels in a WindowsForm but you can use Label.DrawBitmap. And if you are using Label and GDI instead of GDI+, some of the character on your label (and after on bitmap) wont be renderer correctly.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer is wrong. If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault.aspx, it says true = GDI+, false = GDI TextRenderer.

Comment: This is wrong. [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault.aspx) state the default is `false`. Skipping this method is the same as calling it with a value of `false`. Before .NET 2.0, GDI+ Graphics was used for drawing many controls, but due to performance issues, .NET 2.0 and later use GDI TextRenderer. `true` specifies that the application should draw controls using pre-.NET2.0 behavior. Unless you are upgrading a .NET 1.x application, you shouldn't need this method at all. **GDI+ is the old way, GDI is the new way.**

Comment: You're right, guys. I mixed up the values of the parameter. Thanks for catching that mistake.

Answer (score 15):

Back in .NET 1.x, the GDI+ Graphics class was used to render certain controls. Due to performance issues, this approach was scrapped thus .NET version 2.0 and later use the GDI TextRenderer class instead.

Calling `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true)` forces some controls to use their *old*, pre-2.0 rendering.

Unless you are upgrading a .NET 1.x application, and need to keep the old style, you should always use `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`. Or you can remove this call entirely; since `false` is the default, an explicit `false` call is not necessary.

Further reading can be found at the [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

defaultValue
    Type: System.Boolean
    The default value to use for new controls. If true, new controls that support UseCompatibleTextRendering use the GDI+ based Graphics class for text rendering; if false, new controls use the GDI based TextRenderer class.